# Visual Studio Code in Django

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

I'm confused why my Vs Code didn't recognize my Django it shows error in my vscode but actually it's not error in coding. I have Django version 2.2.16 and I already installed Django in Vscode and python 3.5 as well. Can anyone know about this?

[image]

Comment: In bottom right corner your language mode is set to Python . can you try changing it to Django . does it help?

Comment: @Gautamrk Thanks for your response but when I change it to Django, my script change to ordinary script it did not highlight the code anymore like this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aqcop.png), do you know what's the problem? Or does the problem is I download Django in Vscode in different version?

Comment: What does it show when you hover over the read squiggles? Open a new terminal and choose the Problem, what's the content, please post screenshot.

Comment: @MollyWang Is this what you mean? [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8LLi.png)

Comment: yes，i'm happy that you've solved it by installing the required module: pylint-django .

Answer (score 1):

It works fine now I just install `python -m pip install pylint-django` and the error never exist anymore.